# Fatal error: Class Helper_Data' not found in app\Mage.php

Tags: error, class, not-found

Please help me guys to fix it :

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Parcelamento_Helper_Data' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

**Error log**

> Warning: include(Mage\Parcelamento\Helper\Data.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line
>   94

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1) Either you declared your helper in the `config.xml` and you did not create it in the module `NameSpace/NameModule/Helper/Data.php`

2) Either you created it in the module but not in the `config.xml` or you did it wrong.

Solution:

You should have this in your `config.xml`:

```
<global>
  ...
    <helpers>
        <parcelamento>
            <class>Namespace_Parcelamento_Helper</class>
        </parcelamento>
    </helpers>
  ...
</global>
```

You should also have this in :`Namespace/Parcelamento/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class Namespace_Parcelamento_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Now you can call your helper like this:

```
<?php Mage::helper('parcelamento')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your code you will find code as below

```
Mage::helper('parcelamento')
```

Check in your module config file have helper name like bwlow.

```
<helpers>
    <module>
       <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </module>
</helpers>
```

replace **Parcelamento** with your helper name

Comment: Thank you everyone, It's right now ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the website and admin panel live again, I disabled the compilation via SFTP.

You can do that by editing the **root/includes/config.php** file.

To disable compilation in Magento, edit **includes/config.php,** comment out the first line **(line 28)** and uncomment out the second line **(line 29).**

Your final code should look like this (without brackets):

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');  
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Hope this helps.