# Please help me guys to fix it :

Tags: magento-1.9

**Fatal error:** Class 'Magehit_FeaturedProducts_Helper_Data' not found in

```
D:\wamp\www\magento_test\app\Mage.php on line 547.
```

Comment: You are missing your helper. create an helper class and declare it in config.xml

Comment: how to declare it in config.xml

Comment: refer this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180621/fatal-error-class-helper-data-not-found-in-app-mage-php

Comment: is this write or wrong ?  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Magehit_FeaturedProducts>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>1.0.6</version>
    </Magehit_FeaturedProducts>
  </modules>
</config>  this add to config.xml file

Comment: Above mentioned code should be in app/etc/modules. This is not a config.xml code

Comment: read this tutorial https://www.multidots.com/step-by-step-guide-for-magento-module-development