# Fatal error: Class Helper_Data not found in app\Mage.php

Tags: magento-1.9, helper

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Category_Password_Helper_Data' not found in /home/pypub/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

I've read this: [Fatal error: Class Helper_Data' not found in app\Mage.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180621/fatal-error-class-helper-data-not-found-in-app-mage-php) but can't seem to fix it

config:

```
<global>
        <helpers>
            <CategoryPassword>
                <class>SUN_CategoryPassword_Helper</class>
            </CategoryPassword>
        </helpers>
```

SUN/CategoryPassword/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class SUN_CategoryPassword_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

Is it something to do with Category_Password vs CategoryPassword?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have -

```
<!-- Your module - app/code/local/Sun/CategoryPassword-->
<!-- Config - app/code/local/Sun/CategoryPassword/etc/config.xml:-->

<helpers>
    <sun_categorypassword>
        <class>Sun_CategoryPassword_Helper</class>
    </sun_categorypassword>
</helpers>

<!-- Data helper - app/code/local/Sun/CategoryPassword/Helper/Data.php-->
<?php
class Sun_CategoryPassword_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function helloWorld()
    {
        echo "Hello World!!!";
    }
}

// Call on the Data.php helper
Mage::helper('offset101_helpertest')->helloWorld();

rm -rf var/cache
```

Above should work !